# The Expression Refers to Multiple Columns. Multiple Columns Cannot Be Converted to a Scale

Tags: powerbi, dax

below I have this dax code that is supposed to get me the average for each column (SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, MARTURED UNRIPED, MATURED RIPED, DISEASED) in the table podcount.

It is also supposed to allow me create a projection for a certain number of period based on the date. However, my DAX code generates this error: "The Expression Refers to Multiple Columns. Multiple Columns Cannot Be Converted to a Scale"

Please help. Details below.

Table:

[image]

Dax Code:

```
PredictedAverages =
VAR Small_Maturity = 3 * 30,  // Assuming 1 month = 30 days
    Medium_Maturity = 2.5 * 30,
    Large_Maturity = 1.5 * 30,
    Matured_Unriped_Maturity = 14,
    Matured_Riped_Maturity = 0  // Assuming 'Now' means no additional maturity time
RETURN
SUMMARIZE(
    'podcount',
    'podcount'[COMMUNITY],
    'podcount'[DATE],
    "Total_Average_SMALL", SUMX(FILTER('podcount', 'podcount'[SMALL] <> BLANK()), 'podcount'[SMALL] / Small_Maturity),
    "Total_Average_MEDIUM", SUMX(FILTER('podcount', 'podcount'[MEDIUM] <> BLANK()), 'podcount'[MEDIUM] / Medium_Maturity),
    "Total_Average_LARGE", SUMX(FILTER('podcount', 'podcount'[LARGE] <> BLANK()), 'podcount'[LARGE] / Large_Maturity),
    "Total_Average_MATURED_UNRIPED", SUMX(FILTER('podcount', 'podcount'[MATURED UNRIPED] <> BLANK()), 'podcount'[MATURED UNRIPED] / Matured_Unriped_Maturity),
    "Total_Average_MATURED_RIPED", SUMX(FILTER('podcount', 'podcount'[MATURED RIPED] <> BLANK()), 'podcount'[MATURED RIPED] / Matured_Riped_Maturity)
)
```

I have modified the code first to calculate averages into another table called AveragesTable
Before summarizing the averages. Code below:

```
PredictedAverages =
VAR Small_Maturity = 3 * 30  // Assuming 1 month = 30 days
VAR Medium_Maturity = 2.5 * 30
VAR Large_Maturity = 1.5 * 30
VAR Matured_Unriped_Maturity = 14
VAR Matured_Riped_Maturity = 0  // Assuming 'Now' means no additional maturity time

// Calculate averages
VAR AveragesTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        'podcount',
        "Average_SMALL", 'podcount'[SMALL] / Small_Maturity,
        "Average_MEDIUM", 'podcount'[MEDIUM] / Medium_Maturity,
        "Average_LARGE", 'podcount'[LARGE] / Large_Maturity,
        "Average_MATURED_UNRIPED", 'podcount'[MATURED UNRIPED] / Matured_Unriped_Maturity,
        "Average_MATURED_RIPED", 'podcount'[MATURED RIPED] / Matured_Riped_Maturity
    )

// Summarize the averages
RETURN
SUMMARIZE(
    AveragesTable,
    'podcount'[COMMUNITY],
    'podcount'[NAME],
    "Total_Average_SMALL", SUM('AveragesTable'[Average_SMALL]),
    "Total_Average_MEDIUM", SUM('AveragesTable'[Average_MEDIUM]),
    "Total_Average_LARGE", SUM('AveragesTable'[Average_LARGE]),
    "Total_Average_MATURED_UNRIPED", SUM('AveragesTable'[Average_MATURED_UNRIPED]),
    "Total_Average_MATURED_RIPED", SUM('AveragesTable'[Average_MATURED_RIPED])
)
```

Comment: Are you trying to add this as a measure or calculated table?

Comment: I am trying to add it as a measure.

Comment: Well you need to return a single value rather than a whole table which is what SUMMARIZE does.